# SVG textPath: animate linked path

Tags: html, css, svg

is it possible, with  to animate the path on which the text should be rendered?
It seems logic to me: when the d attribute, of the path I'm referring to, will change (cause of a css animation), the text will follow the new path.

```html
<svg>
<style>
    #pt:hover {
        d: path("M0,50 L200,150 L0,150 Z");
    }
</style>
<path id="pt" d="M0,50 L200,50 L0,150 Z" />
<text>
    <textPath href="#pt">INCREDIBLE TEXT</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

It is not possible or am I doing something wrong?
Last thing: what's the use of the path attribute in textPath? I saw that in docs, but I don't know how to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work for me with Firefox.

Comment: Do you see the text follow the path? Why doesn't it move on my side? I tried open it with firefox and it works. In chrome and edge it doesn't work. I'm not getting it

Comment: Presumably Chromium has a bug. The [Chromium bugtracker is here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) on the element.

Keep in mind that then you are animating the d attribute the number of points in the path must be the same (so, the two paths that you defined works fine).

```css
#pt {
  transition: d 4s;
}

#pt:hover {
  d: path("M0,50 L200,150 L0,150 Z");
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path id="pt" d="M0,50 L200,50 L0,150 Z" />
  <text>
    <textPath href="#pt">INCREDIBLE TEXT</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, I omitted the transition property, but this works for you? If I run your snippet the text doesn't move anyway. Maybe, it's my problem? Something about the browser, but my chrome is updated...

Comment: @Sawy hm, I only tested it in Firefox. The same problem for me in Chrome. But it is not an issue with the transition itself -- it is a issue with the text.

Comment: I solve it by adding this <animate attributeName="href" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" values="#pt"> as a child of textPatg tag. Now the path seems to be updated. Could it be a good solution?